# Dropdown default option error in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel blade, I'm trying to display the default dropdown option which is Select role in French

```
{!! Form::select('roles', $roles, array_merge(['' => 'Veuillez sélectionner un rôle'], $roles), ['class' => 'form-control txt_txt']) !!}
```

But this keeps giving me an error,

```
array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, object given
```

I'm populating that dropdown from the DB, with user roles, Following is my eloquent from the controller

```
$roles = Role::where('name','<>','Admin')->orderBy('name')->pluck('name', 'name');
```

How can I display the default option correctly?

Comment: Please tell us what is in the variable `$roles` What it contains or how to fill it from the backend.

Comment: Ok, so in theory it would only be enough with `array_merge(['' => 'Veuillez sélectionner un rôle'], $roles->toArray())` Or you can also do it in the backend `$roles = Role::where('name','<>','Admin')->orderBy('name')->pluck('name', 'name')->toArray();`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `Form::select` incorrectly. It should be like:

```php
Form::select(name, list, selected, selectAttributes, optionsAttributes, optgroupsAttributes);
```

So your code should be like this:

```php
{!!
Form::select(
    'roles',
    array_merge(['' => 'Veuillez sélectionner un rôle'], $roles->toArray())
    '',
    array(
        'class' => 'form-control txt_txt'
    ))
!!}
```